# Wall jump without returning to wall

Tags: unity, character, jumping, character-controller

**In my 2D Platformer character controller that has both a wall jump and a double jump ability, how would I approach implementing a feature that stops the player from returning to the wall they initiated a wall jump from, while still making sure my controls feel responsive? (like they did in Celeste, apart from the double jump)**

So far, I have got a *timer* that starts when the player *initiates* the wall jump and *stops* the player from moving until the timer is over. I'm already not too happy with that approach because it leads to this moment where it feels like player input is basically ignored.

Now in addition, I realised that *after* the timer is over, while just pressing left won't be enough to return to (a higher part of) the wall, simply doing a second jump will enable the player to easily make their way up the wall.

Comment: Do you have any way to store what the last wall is the player jumped from?

Comment: I can work out whether that wall is to the player's left or right, but nothing more specific than that.

Comment: @Ben What engine are you using?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using Unity

Comment: Don't reset the double-jump when they touch the wall. That way, they can jump, wall-jump, double-jump, wall-jump again, but that's it.